# How to call a method which has a parameter of type ILogger

Tags: c#, logging

I want to call a method whose definition is as follows

```
public async Task SomeMethod(string name, bool isWindowsOs, ILogger log)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.isWindows = isWindowsOs;
    this.logger = log;   
    string configPath = 
        Utility.GetFilePathAsPerOs(this.ConfigurationFilePath, isWindows);

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{ConfigPath} was not found");
        logger.Error($"[{this.Name}] : Configuration file not found");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }  
    // Rest of the Code
}
```

As i have not dealt with logging before i am confused about what parameter to pass for ILogger type when i call the Initialise method. Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: which type of project is this is it  asp.net core?

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel I am developing a Console app(.NET Core)  to test a Class library which also targets .Net core 2.1.

Comment: You should use a Mock / Stub, if you're testing the method. :)

Comment: Hover over the argument `log`. What type is it? You just need an instance of an implementation of that type. It is unfortunate that the class is not using dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core is backed in dependency injection an ILogger was intended for this to encourage best practices(DI)
but if you want to achieve this in .net Core you have to follow the following steps:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

here I'm supposing to use the console for the logging

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
```

and you can try something like this:

```
 class Program
    {
        private  static ILogger logger;
        private bool isWindows;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
          ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole();



            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

            logger.LogError("ooops");
            await new Program().SomeMethod("name", true, logger);

           Console.ReadLine();



        }
        public async Task SomeMethod(string name, bool isWindowsOs, ILogger log)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.isWindows = isWindowsOs;
            logger = log;
            //string configPath =
            //    Utility.GetFilePathAsPerOs(this.ConfigurationFilePath,
            //        isWindows);

            //if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigPath))
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine($"{ConfigPath} was not found");
            //    logger.Error($"[{this.Name}] : Configuration file not found");
            //    await Task.CompletedTask;
            //}
             logger.LogInformation("this is just confirmation for a successfull task");
            logger.LogError("ooops");

            // Rest of the Code
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

the result

```
fail: ConsoleApp1.Program[0]
      ooops
info: ConsoleApp1.Program[0]
      this is just confirmation for a successfull task
fail: ConsoleApp1.Program[0]
      ooops
```

**Note**
*this example use a console as provider and you may add another provider like Serilog or Nlog*

*this example use `async Task Main`  which needs c# 7.1 support features enabled*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look here for [Logging best practices](https://stackify.com/csharp-logging-best-practices/) but since Logger implements ILogger (and I guess you are using Log4Net), your call to the method would look like that:

```
//class code
Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
var result = AsyncContext.RunTask(MyAsyncMethod("", true, log).Result;

//log method
public async Task SomeMethod(string name, bool isWindowsOs, ILogger log)
{
            this.Name = name;
            this.isWindows = isWindowsOs;
            this.logger = log;   
            string configPath = 
            Utility.GetFilePathAsPerOs(this.ConfigurationFilePath, 
                       isWindows);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ConfigPath} was not found");
                logger.Error($"[{this.Name}] : Configuration file not found");
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            }  
            // Rest of the Code
}
```

That is the basic snippet, you can call the async method in numerous ways and take it wherever you want.

Comment: If OP is confused about ILogger why would you show AsyncContext without any explanation and when a simple `await` would suffice?

Comment: The op can take it wherever he wants, the OP's question was about how to pass ILogger to method. How you call a task is a different question and everyone has it's own opinion regarding this one :)

Comment: Yes, but when OP pastes your code there are now two questions instead of one. AsyncContext is not widely used or known so there will not be a reference to it already.

Comment: This is why I said: "That is the basic snippet, you can call the async method in numerous ways and take it wherever you want." It gives him another thing to investigate and study about. This is the beauty of software, you investigate and study.